# Tensorflow: "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y' with dtype float and shape [?,2]"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

My code fails with the error (in Android Studio):

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
```

I've been forever trying to figure this out and still can't. I've changed "names", in the Android code and on Python but still nothing.

This is the Python code for running and training the model:

```
# Import packages
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pickle

#
# Import data
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep=",",
                   names=["PEEK", "AFTER_PEEK", "CLASS"])
#
# Shuffle data
data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
#
# Then split `x`, whose columns are normalized to 1, and `y`, one-hot encoded
all_x = data[["PEEK", "AFTER_PEEK"]]
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
all_x = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(all_x)
all_y = pd.get_dummies(data.CLASS)
#
# ... and split training and test set
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(all_x, all_y, test_size=1 / 3)
#
# Check the dimensions
print(train_x.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_x.shape)
print(test_y.shape)
#
# and define number of features, n_x, and number of classes, n_y
n_x = np.shape(train_x)[1]
n_y = np.shape(train_y)[1]
#

# Reset graph
tf.reset_default_graph()
#
# Define learning rate
learning_rate = 0.01
#
# Start graph definition...
##tf.reset_default_graph()
g = tf.Graph()
# ... and placeholders
with g.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_x], name="x")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_y], name="y")
#

# Define the number of neurons for each hidden layer:
h1 = 10
h2 = 20
h3 = 10
#
# From input to 1st hidden layer
with g.as_default():
    fully_connected1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=x, num_outputs=h1, 
                                                         activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn1")
#

# From 1st to 3rd hidden layer, through the 2nd
with g.as_default():
    fully_connected2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected1, num_outputs=h2, 
                                                         activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn2")
    fully_connected3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected2, num_outputs=h3, 
                                                         activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn3")
#

# From 3rd hidden layer to output
with g.as_default():
    prediction = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected3, num_outputs=n_y, 
                                               activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,scope="Out")

# Cost function
with g.as_default():
   cost = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y, logits=prediction,scope="Cost_Function")
#

# Accuracy estimator and optimizer
with g.as_default():
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1, name="Argmax_Pred"), tf.argmax(y, 1, name="Y_Pred"), 
                                  name="Correct_Pred")
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32, name="Cast_Corr_Pred"), name="Accuracy")
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate, name="Optimizer").minimize(cost)
#


####### TRAINING #######

# Start the session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph = g)
#

# Initialize variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
#

# Train for a number of epochs
training_epochs = 3000
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    p , c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
#

##correct_prediction.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y})
#

# Evaluate accuracy
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y}))

pickle.dump(p, open("predictions.p", "wb"))
pickle.dump(c, open("history.p", "wb"))
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', './checkpoint/har.pbtxt') 
saver.save(sess, save_path = "./checkpoint/har.ckpt")
sess.close()
```

This one is for exporting the model:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

MODEL_NAME = 'har'

input_graph_path = 'checkpoint/' + MODEL_NAME+'.pbtxt'
checkpoint_path = './checkpoint/' +MODEL_NAME+'.ckpt'
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_frozen_graph_name = 'frozen_'+MODEL_NAME+'.pb'

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver="",
                          input_binary=False, input_checkpoint=checkpoint_path, 
                          output_node_names="Correct_Pred", restore_op_name="save/restore_all",
                          filename_tensor_name="save/Const:0", 
                          output_graph=output_frozen_graph_name, clear_devices=True, initializer_nodes="")
```

And the dataset looks like this:

```
1.0249,1.0144,0
1.0032,1.0017,0
1.022,0.99394,0
1.0285,1.0095,0
1.0063,1.0009,0
0.98591,1.0067,1
0.98153,1.0133,1
0.97366,1.0215,1
0.98252,1.0311,0
0.99677,1.0379,0
1.0144,1.0466,0
1.0017,1.0536,0
...
```

This is the way I implementend the model on my android App:

```
package com.example.daniel.app03;

import android.content.Context;

import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;


public class TensorFlowClassifier {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
    }

    private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/frozen_har.pb";
    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "x";
    private static final String[] OUTPUT_NODES = {"Correct_Pred"};
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE = "Correct_Pred";
    private static final long[] INPUT_SIZE = {1, 1, 2};
    private static final int OUTPUT_SIZE = 2;

    public TensorFlowClassifier(final Context context) {
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
    }

    public float[] predictProbabilities(float[] data) {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, data, INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of the error? Would be helpful to know what line it's coming from!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using "Correct_Pred" as the output of your inference network.

The reason it's throwing the error about needing a value for `y` is that in your TensorFlow Python code you defined `Correct_Pred` with this line:

`tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1, name="Argmax_Pred"), tf.argmax(y, 1, name="Y_Pred"), name="Correct_Pred")`.

This means that when you try to run `Correct_Pred` in your android code, it will attempt to compute `tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1, name="Argmax_Pred"), tf.argmax(y, 1, name="Y_Pred")`. You can see that you use the placeholder `y` in this computation, so it's expecting a value for `y` to be in the feed dict when you run it.

I suspect that the deeper problem here is that you don't want your `OUTPUT_NODE` to be `Correct_Pred` at all. `Correct_Pred` seems to be a boolean that tells you whether the prediction from your network (`Argmax_pred`) matched the label in your data (`Y_Pred`). For inference in your android app, you will not have labels, so you probably want your `OUTPUT_NODE` to be `Argmax_Pred` (the prediction from your network) instead.

If I'm correct and that is what you want, you can solve this by changing your model export code to:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

MODEL_NAME = 'har'

input_graph_path = 'checkpoint/' + MODEL_NAME+'.pbtxt'
checkpoint_path = './checkpoint/' +MODEL_NAME+'.ckpt'
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_frozen_graph_name = 'frozen_'+MODEL_NAME+'.pb'

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver="",
                          input_binary=False, input_checkpoint=checkpoint_path, 
                          output_node_names="Argmax_Pred", restore_op_name="save/restore_all",
                          filename_tensor_name="save/Const:0", 
                          output_graph=output_frozen_graph_name, clear_devices=True, initializer_nodes="")
```

And change your android code to

```
package com.example.daniel.app03;

import android.content.Context;

import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;


public class TensorFlowClassifier {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
    }

    private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/frozen_har.pb";
    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "x";
    private static final String[] OUTPUT_NODES = {"Argmax_Pred"};
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE = "Argmax_Pred";
    private static final long[] INPUT_SIZE = {1, 1, 2};
    private static final int OUTPUT_SIZE = 1;

    public TensorFlowClassifier(final Context context) {
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
    }

    public float[] predictProbabilities(float[] data) {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, data, INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note the only edits here were changing all occurrences of `Correct_Pred` to `Argmax_Pred`. I also changed your `OUTPUT_SIZE` to 1, because `Argmax_Pred` is the result of an argmax operation, which will return a single scalar value.